# Good strategy for spatial sampling and accuracy assessment

Tags: classification, sampling, random-forest

I have to classify satellite images using machine learning algorithm, preferably Random Forest.I have read in several papers that sampling should be balanced and  in some papers I found that training data should be spatially balanced (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/geostatistical-analyst/create-spatially-balanced-points.htm).

Also, after classification I have to evaluate the model performance and uncertainty in classification. For model performance people suggested ROC and AUC curve. For uncertainty mapping I have no idea.

Any guidance in this regard will be very helpful.
THanks

Comment: For classification algorithms people often estimate the classification error rates. Estimates can be obtained using cross-validation or bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I have found this also in literature.Any idea about uncertainty in RF classification. I came across following link "http://shftan.github.io/surfin/demo.html"

Comment: i published some books on the bootstrap. The most recent being in 2007 "An Introduction to Bootstrap Methods with Applications to R" published by Wiley and coauthored with Robert LaBudde. My book covers papers by Efron and some that I published with Murthy and Nealy on simulation studies that compared error rate estimators (mainly by resampling) when applying linear discriminant analysis. Chapter 2 of my 2007 book touches on bagging, classification trees and random forests providing some references. But I do not go into detail & of course isn't up to date with current literature..

Comment: OK thanks, I will look into that...